# Testing cache.manifest on an iPad with Apache Web Server 2

Tags: ipad, html, manifest, offline

I am trying to build an offline web app for the iPad, and I am trying to verify that the cache.manifest is being served correctly by Apache Web Server 2, and is working. I have added an 'AddType' for the .manifest extension to the mime-types configuration file for the Apache web server.

If I look at the access logs, the first request to the cache-manifest is returned with a 200 HTTP response code, any further requests are served with 304, which is 'not modified'. I take this to mean it is working. The assets (html, images) are returned with a combination of both (200, then 304 as above) so indicates it is working.

When I load it on the iPad, I get the page, but when I go offline, and reload it is unable to load as it does not have a connection to the internet.

I am serving it off the Apache web server of my Mac, so having trouble reliably testing it with my Mac. Any ideas on what is going wrong, or how to verify it is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing the cache manifest is somewhat of a pain in general, but there are a few useful techniques.

First, start with testing it using Safari on the Mac directly.  Just turn off Apache when you want to check it in offline mode.

In Safari, open the Activity monitor and look for any resources that are listed as "cancelled" -- those are typically ones that are missing from the manifest.

Also use the Web Inspector to check the response-type of the manifest file.

In most cases the problem is that you have resources in the application which aren't specified in the manifest; this causes the whole caching operation to fail.  Unfortunately there's no method in the HTML5 API to list *which* resources failed; this would be supremely helpful to developers.

Comment: I couldn't find the Activity monitor in Safari! I tested in chrome (which shows contents of application cache, and also logs the application events), and it is working. I am just having trouble testing on the iPad. I believe I have had it working for a basic example with images, as I turn wifi off, and when entering a url it comes up with the images, which are on a second page that I hadn't visited before. When I do anything more complicated like add a video, it gives the 'not connected to network' error which leads me to believe I don't have it working correctly!

Comment: Apple has confirmed in the past that video simply doesn't work at all offline. I haven't tested it personally.